# IE PNG transparency issue + TwinHelix

Tags: css, .htaccess, image, png, internet-explorer-6

I'm trying to implement the [Twin Helix](http://www.twinhelix.com/css/iepngfix/) PNG transparency issue in IE6 but when I downloaded the zip file the htaccess file is empty. Does anyone know what should be inside the file in order to complete the fix?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .htaccess file is not empty for me. It says:

```
AddType text/x-component .htc
```

Comment: the .htc is supposed to link to the location of the blank.gif from what I understand but as you've found out above, it is not.